# Writing a bash script from java

Tags: java, bash

I have a java program that writes a bash script. Unfortunately when this script is saved, I need to modify it (ubuntu 10.04) to enable running it as an executable. Any way of circumventing this?

I understand that it is a security thing...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
bashScriptFile.setExecutable(true);
```

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#setExecutable%28boolean%29

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using JDK 1.6 you can do following:

After writting file you can do something like

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod +x "+yourfile.sh);
```

Comment: This method i smore dependent on the platform, chmod being not available everywhere.

Comment: This solution should work for mentioned OS ubuntu in question.